# Selenium - Internet explorer - Java - How to disable images loading?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

To improve the performance of the automation, trying to disable image loading.

I found a way to do it in Firefox & Chrome (Ref: [Selenium WebDriver/Firefox|Chrome/Java How to disable image loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306556/selenium-webdriver-firefoxchrome-java-how-to-disable-image-loading)), **not Internet Explorer**. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer, received from Selenium team.

Ref: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7512

> This isn’t possible without changing the browser configuration/profile, and IE does not support profiles outside the currently logged in Windows user account. The driver will not be modified to change the configuration, since there is no guaranteed way to revert the configuration change after the session ends. You can either manually set the browser configuration in the options dialog (if such a setting exists), manipulate the setting programmatically using the Windows registry (assuming such a setting exists for IE), or use a web proxy to block retrieval of images. This is not a feature the driver will be implementing.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of the *automated program* **disableing** the image loading within [internetexplorer](/questions/tagged/internetexplorer) you need to **modify** the *data* for the *name* **`Display Inline Images`** within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` through the *Registry Editor* as **no** as follows:

```
Value name              Value data
---------------------   ----------
Display Inline Images   No
```

Snapshot:

[image: IE_Display_inline_Images]

Comment: I need to run the test on remote machine. So the given solution doesn't work for me. Is there any way to handle through the selenium code(Desired capabilities)?

Comment: @SandeepNalla Of coarse there is but that would be a separate question all together.

Comment: Do you know how to handle this through the Selenium code?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the images while browsing on Internet Explorer, you could open the **Internet Options** and go to the **Advanced Ta**b. Scroll down to Multimedia Section and uncheck **Show Pictures** check-box, click **Apply** and Exit.

[image]

Comment: I need to run the test on remote machine. So the given solution doesn't work for me. Is there any way to handle through the selenium code(Desired capabilities)?

Comment: As far as I know, Internet Explorer doesn’t provide any option for disabling images through Selenium web driver, we could only disable it from IE internet options and Registry. You could post your problem on [selenium forum](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) or feedback this new feature from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: Opened a ticket in Selenium forum.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7512